# How to include authorization in http link?

Tags: google-chrome, http, http-headers, http-live-streaming, ip-camera

I have a live stream that you can access via ip example:
123.123.123.123:1234/video

On opening directly you are prompted for credentials.

Now i want to embed this on my website.

```
<img src="http://admin:examplepass@123.123.123.123:1234/video" />
```

wont work. After reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication.

I tried encoding 'admin:examplepass' but then you get something like

```
<img src="http://QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l@123.123.123.123:1234/video" />
```

Which does not work. Im at loss here, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your first try should have been successfull as it adheres to [RFC 3986, sec. 3.2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.1). Can you explain in more detail what "won't work" means? It would also help if you could check what is going on on the network layer via [Chrome's network panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#network_panel).

Comment: @DaSourcerer Chrome blocks it http://stackoverflow.com/q/36217887/6427829